# Spaces behind \textgreater not working as expected

Tags: spacing, formatting

I have the following code:

```
 \textit{WMC \textgreater   average}
```

But the text looks like this:

> WMC >average

It does not even change if I add even more spaces. So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is because [commands gobble spaces](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-xspace). The simple work around is to type `\textgreater{}` to terminate the command, which will restore the space after the command. See the linked TeX FAQ entry for other possible solutions.

Comment: Or an explicitly space can be added: `\textgreater\space`. In the OP's example it doesn't make any difference, but e.g. inside an`\edef` context it would make one.

Comment: Another option is to put a control space: `\textgreater\ average`.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use [the `xspace` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/xspace) if you don't want to manually insert a space after each use, to intelligently insert a space as needed:

[image]

### Notes:

- Granted that this is very unlikely usage for `\textgreater` (where you would *not* want a space after the symbol), but using `\xspace` is useful in other similar situations such as [Have a space after \texttrademark oder any kind of characters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79760/have-a-space-after-texttrademark-oder-any-kind-of-characters).

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xspace}

\let\OldTextgreater\textgreater
\renewcommand{\textgreater}{\OldTextgreater\xspace}%

\begin{document}
WMC \textgreater  average.

Using \verb|\textgreater| yields \textgreater.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `\space` after the word a blank space should be placed.

**Code:**

`\textit{WMC \textgreater \space average}`

**Result:**

[image]