# Have a space after \texttrademark oder any kind of characters

Tags: spacing, symbols, formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Spaces behind \textgreater not working as expected](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14526/spaces-behind-textgreater-not-working-as-expected)

I am faced with the following problem. I write a document in which I refer to a registered brand and thus looks like "MyBrand\textrademark" and this work. However, there is no spcae before the consecutive word even if I add a lot of spaces. The easiest fix I have found so far is to a dd an ”~" but isn't there a nicer way ?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) The usual way is to use either `\texttrademark{} nextword` or `\texttrademark\ nextword`.

Comment: `\,` or `\thinspace` or `\enspace`

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer and comments. I agree with Qrrbrbirlbel and I think it is a duplicate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't want to manually insert a space after each use, you could use the [the `xspace` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/xspace) to intelligently insert a space as needed:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xspace}

\let\OldTexttrademark\texttrademark
\renewcommand{\texttrademark}{\OldTexttrademark\xspace}%

\begin{document}
MyBrand\texttrademark is cool.

A cool brand is MyBrand\texttrademark.

\end{document}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for `\textregistered` though. Perhaps is also font related...

Comment: @rbaleksandar: Seems to work for me. Perhaps you should post a question with a  [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) that illustrates the problem.

Comment: You are right, it works. I just had the `\renewcommand` before I was including a style which overrides my changes internally. Placing it after that made it work. ^_^